# Changing user password using admin interface on django

Tags: django, apache, admin

I try to change user password using the standard form in the admin interface but when i enter new password and hit ok i get this message:

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /admin/auth/user/3/ on this server.

Apache Server at <my-site-name>.com Port 80
```

And then I have no posibility to load admin page (I get the same error) until I delete all cookies from this site. When I check new password I find it successfully changed. Is there any way to solve this problem? Thanks!

Comment: The problem is solved! It was because the server had sql injection protection which classified queries as an attack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved! It was because the server had sql injection protection which classified queries as an attack